# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Xcode when Reading Element from file in C

Tags: c, xcode

I keep running in to this issue when trying to read any data from a file (the files first line does contain a number). To do this I used

```
fscanf(Read_File, "%d", &Number);
```

This is my full code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char Name[50] = "Test";
    int Number = 5;
    
    FILE* Read_File;
    
    Read_File = fopen("Employee Details.txt", "r");
    
    fscanf(Read_File, "%d", &Number);
    
    printf("%d", Number);
    
    //puts(Name);
}
```

Each time I try and run this though I get the error in the image bellow.
[Image Or Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKMjv.png)

This is something that I have done before when using Visual Studio but that dosent seem to be available for Mac, and since I switched recently Xcode seems to be my best bet.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: PSA: When calling operations that might fail, like `fopen`, **always** test the result given. You may be trying to proceed with a `NULL` pointer, which is invalid and will crash.

Comment: It's also worth noting, before you get far into C, that there's a strong convention for variables to be lower-case only, like `name` or `number`. It's up to you what to call them in the end, there's no restrictions as such, but following conventions makes your code a lot easier to work with and understand.

Answer (score 1):

The default assumption for this sort of crash is a memory management error. In this case, it seems that the program was unable to find the file, which resulted in `fopen()` returning a null pointer, which was later passed to `fscanf()`, and hence undefined behaviour was invoked. Consider:

```
#if 0
    Read_File = fopen("Employee Details.txt", "r");
#else
    #include <errno.h>
   
    Read_File = (errno = 0, fopen("Employee Details.txt", "r"));
    
    if (!Read_File) {
        errno ? perror("fopen()") : (void) fputs( /* Error message. */, stderr);
        /* Handle error here. */
    }

    /* Safe to use the pointer now. */
#endif
```

Also consider checking the return value of `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

> the files first line does contain a number

I would like to believe you, yet code should operate even if such assurances are false.

**Check the return value of functions** `fopen()` and `fscanf()`.

```
    // Read_File = fopen("Employee Details.txt", "r");
    // fscanf(Read_File, "%d", &Number);
    // printf("%d", Number);

    const char *fname = "Employee Details.txt";
    Read_File = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (Read_File == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file <%s>.\n", fname);
    } else {
      if (fscanf(Read_File, "%d", &Number) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read an int from <%s>.\n", fname);
      } else {
        printf("%d", Number);
      }
      fclose(Read_File);  // Be sure to put away your resources when done.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine per testing on my side.  It is highly likely that your program does not find your file during run time -- hence throwing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception -- because the code tries to read from a stream that is actually not available to the program.

Here is your code, adjusted to 1.) only attempt file read if the file is found and opened, and 2.) alert the user if the file failed to open.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int number = 5;
    FILE* read_file;
    
    read_file = fopen("Employee Details.txt", "r");
    if(read_file)  /* Added:  ensure file pointer not NULL */
    {
        fscanf(read_file, "%d", &number);
        printf("%d\n", number);
    }
    else
    {   /* Execution comes here if file failed to open. */
        printf("File open failed!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```